# ALU verilog test bench not sure initialized properly

Tags: testing, verilog, alu

I'm trying to write the test bench for my ALU but. I'm not sure if its written in a way that makes it work. For instance, should I use `dut` or `uut`?  Have I initialized my inputs correctly? The output wave is just straight (doesn't change with each bit X's and one 0).

```
module Alu_test();
  reg [7:0]pc;
  reg [3:0] CCRin;
  reg rst,clk;
  reg [3:0] opcode;
  reg[7:0] ra;
  reg[7:0] rb; 
  reg [7:0] in_port;
  reg[7:0] SP;         //= 255
  wire[7:0] SP_out;
  wire [7:0] out_port;
  wire[255:0] dmem;
  wire[7:0] ra_out;
  wire[7:0] rb_out;
  wire [3:0] CCRo; 
  wire [7:0] npc;
  
  
ALU dut(opcode,ra,rb,ra_out,rb_out,rst,clk,pc,npc,CCRin,CCRo,SP,SP_out,in_port,out_port,dmem);
initial 
begin
rst = 0;
clk = 0;
opcode = 0;
SP = 255;
CCRin = 0;
pc = 0;
in_port = 0;
ra = 0;
rb = 0;
#5
forever
    #5 clk = ~clk;

#50

#5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b0000; //nop


#5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b0100; //add
ra =1;
rb =1;

#5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b0111; //shift left
ra =1;
rb =0;

#5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b1010; //push
ra =1;
rb =2;

end
endmodule
```

this is the module

```
module ALU(opcode,ra,rb,ra_out,rb_out,rst,clk,pc,npc,CCRin,CCRo,SP,SP_out,in_port,out_port,dmem);
  wire [7:0] res; // result 
  input wire [7:0]pc;
  output reg [7:0] npc;
  input rst,clk;
  input wire [3:0] opcode;
  input wire[7:0] ra;
  input wire[7:0] rb;
  output reg[7:0] ra_out;
  output reg[7:0] rb_out;
  input wire[7:0] SP; // testbench haygebli SP el mafroud yeb2a = 255
  output reg[7:0] SP_out;
  input wire [7:0] in_port;
  output reg [7:0] out_port;
  
  output reg[255:0] dmem;
  
  input wire [3:0] CCRin;
  output reg [3:0] CCRo;
  wire co;
  wire cin;
  
  wire [7:0] result; //total result
  
 always @(posedge clk)
  begin
   SP_out = SP;
end
  
  assign result = alu_out(ra,rb,cin); 
  assign res = result[1:0];
  assign co = result[2];
  
  
  
  function [8:0] alu_out;
   input [1:0] ra,rb;
   input cin;
   
  case (opcode)
    0: ;
    4: assign alu_out = ra + rb;
    5: assign alu_out = ra - rb;
    6: assign alu_out = ~(ra & rb);
    7: assign alu_out = {ra[7:0],cin};
    8: assign alu_out = {ra[0],cin,ra[7:1]};
    10: if (ra == 1)
          begin
         dmem[SP_out] = rb;
         SP_out = SP_out-1;
       end
     else
       begin
       SP_out = SP_out +1;
       rb_out = dmem[SP_out];
     end
    11: assign out_port = ra;
    12: assign ra_out = in_port;
    13: assign ra_out = rb;
    default: begin
    alu_out = 8'bxxxxxxxx; 
   
      
end
endcase 
endfunction
  always@(posedge clk)
   begin 
  if (res == 0)
     CCRo[0] = 1;
  else if ( res < 0)
   CCRo[1] = 1;
  else if (co == 1)
    CCRo[2] = 1;
  else if ( res < 0 & res > result)
    CCRo[3] = 1;
  else
    CCRo = CCRin;
  if (res)
  ra_out = res;
  
  npc = pc+1;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Does that code really compile? I think it's illegal to have `assign` statements inside a behavioral case block. Should just be `4: alu_out = ...` without the `assign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dut` as the instance name is fine.  You can also use `uut` instead, if you prefer.

You should move the clock generation into its own `initial` block, then call `$finish` at the end of your original `initial` block.  This should get you further.  Now, 4 signals become known:

```
initial begin
    rst = 0;
    opcode = 0;
    SP = 255;
    CCRin = 0;
    pc = 0;
    in_port = 0;
    ra = 0;
    rb = 0;
    #5;
    #50;
    #5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b0000; //nop
    #5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b0100; //add
    ra =1;
    rb =1;
    #5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b0111; //shift left
    ra =1;
    rb =0;
    #5 opcode[3:0] = 4'b1010; //push
    ra =1;
    rb =2;
    $finish;
end

initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
end
```

Your `dmem` initializes to X.  You need to drive in opcode=10 to set it to another value.